# Largest disk contained in an ellipsoid

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, conic-sections

It is known that any ellipsoid with principal semi-axes $a$, $b$, $c$ has circular planar sections (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_section).

- Is the largest circular disk contained within any ellipsoid given by one of its circular sections?
- What is the expression for the radius and other parameters of the largest contained disk  in an ellipsoid in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$?

Comment: Doesn’t the linked wiki article already give a complete answer?

Comment: Thanks. I could not figure out the answer. The largest disk inside an ellipsoid could well be a subset of an elliptical cross section of the ellipsoid - I am not sure if such a possibility is ruled out.

Comment: As per the linked wiki article, any circle in the ellipsoid $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2=1$ with $a<b<c$ belongs to a family of circles obtained as sections with a family of parallel planes. The extremal planes are tangent planes to umbilical points.

Comment: There are exactly $4$ umbilical points in the ellipsoid, as shown here[1], and they belong to the plane $y=0$. In conclusion we have two symmetric 1-parameter families of circles, the largest passing through the origin, with radius $b$ and diameter on the the $y$-axis.
[1]:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022803/umbilical-points-of-ellipsoid-alternate-method

Comment: oh, I see, maybe by "inside an ellipsoid" you mean inside the convex body,  $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2\le1$, not just the surface

Comment: So in this case the question is equivalent to: any plane section of the ellipsoid is an ellipse whose minor semi-axis is $\le b$.

Comment: Thanks very much. I guess the last comment answers the question - the radius of the largest disc contained in an ellipse is given by the second largest of the 3 semi axes.